# for build calculate and make errors

Tags: java, android, xml

in my project for build calculate has error like this :

```
void findView(){

        btn_0=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_0);
           btn_1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
```

and cannot resolve symbol for anythings have R ,what should i do ?

Comment: make sure you have a class or variable called R

Comment: **clean-Rebuild-run** your project

Comment: R is autogenerated and contains all IDs from your layouts etc. This is used to access resource data.

Check that you have no error in Resources like color, layout, style etc. files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145518/1105291

Answer (score 0):

Go to your top nav bar --> Build -- > Clean project --> Rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using gradle as your build tool, the problem is that the gradle is not synced with your project. and keep in mind that if you are developing in a restricted country, try using a proxy while syncing the gradle.

Answer (score 0):

i think  `gradle` is not synced with your project. that's why it giving error that **cannot resolve symbol for anythings have R**

and `R` is autogenerated and contains all IDs from your controls of layouts

so 
 **Build -- > Clean project --> Rebuild project.**

[image]

**to clean project**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Build -- > Clean project --> Rebuild project and run your project again